# pagerank: how to resolve java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, pagerank

I'm trying to implement a pagerank algorithm with 1 million nodes as input.

However, I've got this error. I'm quite sure it's because an open recursive call problem, from generateParamList().

I've tried to make this method a different way not using recursive, but failed again and again. If you let me know how to modify the "generateParamList()", I will appreciate that!!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Ranking.getInboundLinks(Ranking.java:200)
    at Ranking.generateParamList(Ranking.java:172)


    import Jama.Matrix;

    public class Ranking {

    private final double DAMPING_FACTOR = 0.85;

    private List params = new ArrayList();
    private static Map<String, String[]> outlinkMap =   new HashMap();
    private static Map<String, String[]> inlinkMap  =   new HashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Ranking ranking = new Ranking();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("linkgraph_test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;
        String[] tempStringArray = null;

        int iTemp = 0;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            tempStringArray = strLine.split(" ");

            String[] tempValueArray = new String[tempStringArray.length-1];

            for(iTemp=1;iTemp<tempStringArray.length;iTemp++){
                tempValueArray[iTemp-1] = tempStringArray[iTemp];
            }

            outlinkMap.put(tempStringArray[0], tempValueArray);
        }
        in.close();

        setInboundLinks();


        for(int j=1;j<=outlinkMap.size();j++){
            String keytoString = Integer.toString(j);
            System.out.println(keytoString+" "+ranking.rank(keytoString));
        }
    }

    /*
     * 
     * Solve the equation of ax=b, which : a is the generated matrix based on the parameter constants. x is the page ranks matrix. b is a n*1 matrix which all the values are equal to the damping factor.
     * 
     */

    public double rank(String pageId) {

        generateParamList(pageId);
        Matrix a = new Matrix(generateMatrix());
        double[][] arrB = new double[params.size()][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
            arrB[i][0] = 1 - DAMPING_FACTOR;
        }
        Matrix b = new Matrix(arrB);

        // Solve the equation and get the page ranks
        Matrix x = a.solve(b);
        int ind = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (Iterator it = params.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String curPage = (String) it.next();
            if (curPage.equals(pageId))
                ind = cnt;
            cnt++;
        }
        return x.getArray()[ind][0];
    }

    /*
     * 
     * This method generates the matrix of the linear equations. The generated
     * 
     * matrix is a n*n matrix where n is number of the related pages.
     * 
     */
    private double[][] generateMatrix() {
        double[][] arr = new double[params.size()][params.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < params.size(); j++) {
                arr[i][j] = getMultiFactor((String) params.get(i),(String) params.get(j));

            }

        }

        return arr;

    }

    /*
     * 
     * This method returns the constant of the given variable in the linear equation.
     * 
     */

    private double getMultiFactor(String sourceId, String linkId) {
        if (sourceId.equals(linkId))
            return 1;
        if(!sourceId.equals(linkId) && getInboundLinks(sourceId)!=null ) {
            //System.out.println("source"+sourceId+"\tlinkInd"+linkId);
            String[] inc = getInboundLinks(sourceId);
            for (int i = 0; i < inc.length; i++) {
                if (inc[i].equals(linkId)) {
                    return -1*(DAMPING_FACTOR / getOutboundLinks(linkId).length);
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;

    }

    /*
     * 
     * This method returns list of the related pages. This list is also the parameters in the linear equation.
     * 
     */

    private void generateParamList(String pageId) {

        System.out.println("start"+pageId);
        if(getInboundLinks(pageId)!=null){
        // Add the starting page.
        if (!params.contains(pageId))   params.add(pageId);

        // Get list of the inbound pages

            String[] inc = getInboundLinks(pageId);
        // Add the inbound links to the params list and do same for inbound links

            for (int i = 0; i < inc.length; i++) {

                if (!params.contains(inc[i])){
                    generateParamList(inc[i]);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * 
     * Return list of the inbound links to a given page.
     * 
     */

    private String[] getInboundLinks(String pageId) {

        return (String[]) inlinkMap.get(pageId);

    }

private static void setInboundLinks(){

        int valueLength;
        String keytoString;
        String[] outlinkValueArray, inlinkValueArrayTemp, tempCopyArray, resultArray;


        for(int i=1; i<=outlinkMap.size();i++){

            keytoString = Integer.toString(i);
            outlinkValueArray= outlinkMap.get(keytoString);
            if(outlinkValueArray!=null){
                valueLength = outlinkValueArray.length;         
                for(int j=0; j<valueLength;j++){
                    String[] tempValueArray = new String[1];
                    if(!inlinkMap.containsKey(outlinkValueArray[j])){


                        tempValueArray[0] = keytoString;
                        inlinkMap.put(outlinkValueArray[j],tempValueArray);

                    }
                    else{

                        tempCopyArray = inlinkMap.get(outlinkValueArray[j]);
                        tempValueArray[0] = keytoString;

                        resultArray = mergeArray(tempCopyArray, tempValueArray);
                        inlinkMap.put(outlinkValueArray[j],resultArray);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static String[] mergeArray(String[] ar1, String[] ar2){
        String[] ar3 = Arrays.copyOf(ar1, ar1.length+ar2.length);
        System.arraycopy(ar2, 0, ar3, ar1.length, ar2.length);
        return ar3;
    }
    /*
     * 
     * Returns list of the outbound links from a page.
     * 
     */

    private String[] getOutboundLinks(String pageId) {

        // This simulates a simple page collection
        return (String[]) outlinkMap.get(pageId);

    }
}
```

input format:
1 126645 320349 144068 635538 37354 141327 53842 121180 4786 31658 285466 526963 93938 9097 32341 .............
2 ......

Comment: Recursive functions are not good for large data, as it will do to much recursive calls.
In this case you should use loops.

Comment: @SergioGarcia thank you sergio, but could u tell more specific? then how can I modify here : "private void generateParamList(String pageId) {........for (int i = 0; i < inc.length; i++) {if (!params.contains(inc[i])){generateParamList(inc[i]);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you function **generateParamList** for this, it is a non recursive version.
I think it do the same job, please test. I put some comments to help you understand the concept.

```
private void generateParamList(String pageId) {
    // Don't process duplicates
    if (params.contains(pageId)) return;

    // Store links not processed
    Stack<String> links = new Stack<String>();

    // Store current pageId to be processed
    links.push(pageId);

    // Loop, processed the Stack link, not a recursive call
    while (!links.empty()) {
        pageId = links.pop();

        // Link already processed
        if (params.contains(pageId)) continue;

        params.add(pageId);

        // Get list of the inbound pages
        String[] inc = getInboundLinks(pageId);

        for (int i = 0; i < inc.length; i++) {
            // Store link to be processed by the loop
            links.push(inc[i]);
        }
    }
}
```